# How to prevent user from going back with browser after signup?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I'm using [passport](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/downloads/html/) for creating an authentication mechanism in the Node.js application.

Everything is working well but the only issue I have is when I click the back button in the browser, the browser goes back to the signup page.

My Signup Route:

```
const Router = require("express").Router();
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const User = require("../models/user");

Router.post("/", (req, res, next) => {
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) next(err);
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) return next(err);
      const user = new User({ username: req.body.username, password: hash });
      user.save((err, user) => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.redirect("/");
      });
    });
  });
});

Router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    res.redirect("/");
    return;
  }
  res.render("signup");
});

module.exports = Router;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by checking if a user is signed in already and then redirecting then before processing any more work.

```js
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return res.redirect('/')
  } else {
    res.render('signup')
  }
  return next()
})
```